# How to extract slices and specific columns of a numpy array with one command?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to extract both column slices and specific columns of a `numpy` array in one command.

For instance, for an array A:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]])
```

I would like to select the columns from 0 to 2 together with the column 4. The solution `A[:,(0,1,2,4)]` works and is simple to implement in this example. For larger arrays, I am looking for a command of the type `A[:,(0:3,4)]` to select both slices and specific columns. The command `A[:,(0:3,4)]` does not work.

Is there an practical and elegant way of extracting both slices and specific columns with one command?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried using `np.r_`

Comment: You have to, in one way or other, convert the tuple into a list.  `np.r_` does that nicely, but under the covers it uses `arange` to convert the `slice` into an array, and concatenates them all.   An alternative is to do the indexing first, and concatenate the results.  Spends tends to be similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *ombk* suggested, you can use *r_*.
It is a perfect tool to concatenate slice expressions.

In your case:

```
A[:, np.r_[0:3, 4]]
```

retrieves the intended part of your array.

Just the same way you can concatenate more slice expressions.